# Wordpress Woocommerce - use update_post_meta to add multiple products from HTML POST

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce, http-post

First I wanted to say thank you for this website & the contributors, it has provided a wealth of knowledge over the past years to myself for learning about code.

Here is my problem/situation.

I edited/wrote some code to ADD external products from a HTTP POST into Woocommerce. This is working, but it will only add one product (didn't realize I needed it to add multiple).

So here is the HTTP Post code I was provided:

```
$_POST => Array
(
[description] => Array
    (
        [0] => Lloyd Ultimats Mat: UM4 3175560 1 Pc Front Mat ($124.90)
               Mat Color:100 Black
               Chevrolet Silverado 1500 2011
               Model Feature: Extended Cab
               Premium Binding: 508 Silver ($10.00)
               Logo: 819257 ($33.00)
               SS Large 2010 APP Black
               UM4|3175560|446||100|5081||819257|||||
        [1] => Lloyd Ultimats Mat: UM7 3175590 1 Pc 2nd Seat Mat ($74.90)
               Product Feature: Front Bucket Seats
               Mat Color:100 Black
               Chevrolet Silverado 1500 2011
               Model Feature: Extended Cab
               Premium Binding: 508 Silver ($10.00)
               Logo: 819257 ($33.00)
               SS Large 2010 APP Black
               UM7|3175590|4841||100|5081||819257|||||
    )

[total] => Array
    (
        [0] => 167.9
        [1] => 117.9
    )

[wholesale] => Array
    (
        [0] => 100.9
        [1] => 70.9
    )

[retail] => Array
    (
        [0] => 167.9
        [1] => 117.9
    )

[part_number] => Array
    (
        [0] => UM4
        [1] => UM7
    )

[lloyd_code] => Array
    (
        [0] => UM4|3175560|446||100|5081||819257|||||
        [1] => UM7|3175590|4841||100|5081||819257|||||
    )

[weight] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9.00
        [1] => 10.00
    )

[total_rows] => 2
)
```

Here is my PHP code I created, but it only adds one product at a time.

```
 <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
set_time_limit(0);
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php');
add_action('init', '$_POST');
global $woocommerce;
session_start();


if (!isset($_SESSION['lloyd_code'])) {
$_SESSION['lloyd_code'] = Array();
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['weight'])) {
$_SESSION['weight'] = Array();
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['total'])) {
$_SESSION['total'] = array();
}    
if (!isset($_SESSION['description'])) {
$_SESSION['description'] = array();
}

$lloyd_code = $_POST['lloyd_code']['0'];
$weight = $_POST['weight']['0'];
$description = $_POST['description']['0'];
$total = $_POST['total']['0'];

array_push($_SESSION['lloyd_code'], $lloyd_code);
array_push($_SESSION['weight'], $weight);
array_push($_SESSION['description'], $description);
array_push($_SESSION['total'], $total);


$_POST = array(
 'post_author' => "AllAboutFloorMats",
 'post_content' => $description,
 'post_status' => "publish",
 'post_title' => $_POST['description']['0'],
 'post_parent' => '',
 'post_type' => "product",
 'post_excerpt' => $description,
 );
  //Create post
 $post_id = wp_insert_post( $_POST, $wp_error );
 if($post_id){
 $attach_id = get_post_meta($product->parent_id, "_thumbnail_id", true);
 add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
}
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'Lloyds', 'product_cat' );
 wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'simple', 'product_type');


wp_update_post($my_post);
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
 update_post_meta( $post_id, 'total_sales', '0');
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_downloadable', 'no');
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_virtual', 'no');
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', $total, true);
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', $total, true);
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price', $total, true);
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_purchase_note', $description );
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_featured', "no" );
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_weight', $weight, true );
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_length', "" );
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_width', "" );
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_height', "" );
 update_post_meta($post_id, '_sku', $lloyd_code);
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_attributes', array());
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', "" );
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', "" );
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sold_individually', "" );
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_manage_stock', "no" );
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_backorders', "no" );
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock', "" );


$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $post_id, $quantity=1 );
exit( wp_redirect( get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'cart' ) ) ) );
```

I'm kinda lost on how to add these multiple products at the same time.

Again thanks for any help, guidance, assistance you can provide. If you need any additional info, please let me know.

Comment: You need to loop over the products, in the current code I don't see a loop to add multiple products

Comment: Hi Anand,  thanks for the reply.

Any tips, clues on how to create a loop for this php script?  

Thanks

Comment: I've been seeing people use
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
to do loops, but not sure what to input & where to put it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to reference all the elements in the array, currently you are referencing the 1st element only

`$lloyd_code = $_POST['lloyd_code']['0'];  // 0 = first element`

The following code shows how to loop over the products

```
$i = 0;
for ( $i; $i < $_POST['total_rows']; $i++ ) {

$lloyd_code = $_POST['lloyd_code'][$i];
$weight = $_POST['weight'][$i];
$description = $_POST['description'][$i];
$total = $_POST['total'][$i];

// rest of the code continues...

}  //end for loop
```

Please note that down the line in your code you are overwriting the $_POST global, with the following line of code

```
$_POST = array(
 'post_author' => "AllAboutFloorMats",
 'post_content' => $description,
 'post_status' => "publish",
 'post_title' => $_POST['description']['0'],
 'post_parent' => '',
 'post_type' => "product",
 'post_excerpt' => $description,
 );

 $post_id = wp_insert_post( $_POST, $wp_error );
```

Replace `$_POST = array (`  with another variable, perhaps

```
$my_post = array(
 'post_author' => "AllAboutFloorMats",
 'post_content' => $description,
 'post_status' => "publish",
 'post_title' => $_POST['description'][$i],
 'post_parent' => '',
 'post_type' => "product",
 'post_excerpt' => $description,
 );

 $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post, $wp_error );
```

Comment: Awesome! I will try this out & thank you for your help!

Comment: The modifications you provided worked PERFECT!!  thank you so much!

Comment: I am glad I could help. Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the arrow next to my answer.